# How to interpret pci express specification for hba card

Tags: hp, pci-express, hba

I am confused by this spec listed on HP website
http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12907_na/12907_na.HTML

How to interpret the PCIe Connector row correctly?
What is the bandsidth? Does it depend on motherboard PCIe revision?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where your confusion comes from, they're all PCIe 2.0 x 8 physically and will use all 8 lanes if connected to a PCIe 1.0 slot but only 4 lanes if connected to a PCIe 2.0 slot. Given PCIe 1.0 works at 2.5Gbps per lane then that works out at a max of 8 x 2.5Gbps so 20Gbps, a PCIe 2.0 lane runs at 5Gps per lane so we get the same 20Gbps.

Obviously there's no point in being any faster than this as the FC ports can only handle 8Gbps in and out (so 16Gbps combined) so 20Gbps is the best overall PCIe bandwidth profile for these cards.

Comment: Chopper3, you mean if i installed the card on motherboard that support PCIe 3.0 x8 (rated at 64 Gbps at wikipedia), then it will still works at PCIe 2.0 x8 speed?

Comment: Yes, it's a PCIe 2.0 card, not 3.0.